# How could I get a Tab layout like this

Tags: css, tabs

So I'm trying to figure out how best to achieve a Tab layout like this http://reversl.net/tests/ but I'm unsure of the right way to approach it. Originally I thought of creating a UL and floating the list items before adding background color and padding to create the large backgrounds. But I wasn't sure how to achieve the text layout (large number on top of small text)

I'd also like active tabs to have a pointer (as shown) and this lead me to think that maybe instead of a UL I should float 3 dives and make each one a link. However I think this approach would not be very semantic. And now I'm confused :-/ Any tips?

Comment: Can you show want you did till know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This uses an :after pseudo-element for the 'active' indicator which will need a shiv or changing completely if you want it to work in crappy browsers, but it's pretty close to the image:

http://jsfiddle.net/BzSVL/

For the larger text above, I think the most semantic you will get is em or strong as it is an emphasised part of the link text ?

Comment: This is exactly what I was after. Thanks a lot. I think the :after pseudo-element is supported by most browsers bar i.e 6 and 7. I guess I could degrade to an image pointer for these. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

The provided link is just an image.

try this [tabs with css](http://htmlrockstars.com/blog/using-css-to-create-a-tabbed-content-area-no-js-required/)

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following HTML:

```
<ul id="tabs">
    <li>01</li>
    <li>02</li>
    <li>03</li>
</ul>
```

And CSS:

```
#tabs li:after {
    content: " tab";
    font-size: ...;
}
```

Add other elements as needed.